# A different html each time

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 different html pages as my index.html. I want the user to see a different page every time that goes to my address.  So each html could have the same possibilities to be seen. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Serving drastically randomly different content for the same resource is kind of an odd thing to do.  If the markup is truly different, you may be better off using a server-side technology to return the different content.  If you just want the styling to be different, I'd recommend using the same markup with different CSS and then you can use JavaScript (or server-side code as well) to randomly swap out the CSS.

Comment: I want different pages with different designs for different reasons: In the front page to test witch design gives better results (conversion rate in a button). Another reason is to give the same opportunities to the products witch are in different subparts. For instance if I have a link that goes to furniture I think is better to send people directly 33% of the time to the tables, 33% of the times to chairs, 33% of the time to lamps. (If I send people to a generic page for furniture is another unnecessary step)

Comment: For the main page, design testing is a prime example of using different CSS styles with the same content.  You'll want the structure of the content to remain pretty consistent, though.  You can serve up different information in different articles/asides/etc. but you'll want the structure to be consistent.  As for the "furniture" idea, you might want to consider including a "featured" section in the content and making that dynamic, instead of making the entire resource "random."  Not only will randomizing make for a confusing user experience for return visitors, it will ruin your SEO.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand or I don't explain well. I'll give you an example. Amazon or Apple use this sometimes (not now). For instance if you go to apple.com you could see a photo and a text of the iPhone, if you reload the same page you see the iPhone in the small photo at the bottom and for instance the Air and another text in the main part at the top. This is what I try to do.

Comment: Yes, but they're not serving different pages.  They're just populating their pages with dynamic content, using server-side code, in pre-determined places (articles/asides/etc.).  That is, while they use JavaScript for some client-side user experience, and while the content is HTML, they have additional server-side technology driving it.  It sounds like what you're trying to do is build a data-driven web application.  That's a pretty broad and generic topic.  But at the very least it's going to involve more than just HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The following PHP snippet will serve either `indexOne.html`, `indexTwo.html` or `indexThree.html`, if they are in the same directory as the `index.php` (actually the snippet).

```php
<?php

$pages = array( 'indexOne.html', 'indexTwo.html', 'indexThree.html' );
$page = $pages[ rand( 0, count( $pages ) - 1 ) ];
include $page;

?>
```

But as David mentions, it may not be a good practice to do so. You can however include the snippet in a HTML page, only providing - for example - a random product every time.
If you really want dynamic content on your site, it may be a good idea however to use a database for your custom content.